Selenium automating tasks gives stale element reference error
I have a selenium project to save all jobs for certain search words,
and it gave the following error message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DRMINA2019\PycharmProjects\day 50 linkedlin job application\.venv\Scripts\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    job.click()
  File "C:\Users\DRMINA2019\PycharmProjects\day 50 linkedlin job application\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\DRMINA2019\PycharmProjects\day 50 linkedlin job application\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DRMINA2019\PycharmProjects\day 50 linkedlin job application\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\DRMINA2019\PycharmProjects\day 50 linkedlin job application\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=126.0.2592.87); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CA008132+13538]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6C9F91DE9+595465]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DAE6CF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DB37C9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DB56CB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DB5770]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DF440F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DF38B7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE8711]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9E11FFA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE8147]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE800D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9E122E0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE8147]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9E2B1EE]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9E11C63]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE766E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE683C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6C9DE7221]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF6CA1C96D4+1099860]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6C9F0D8FC+53532]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6C9F00E25+1605]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF6CA1C8665+1095653]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6C9F9C961+27777]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6C9F96CE4+4100]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6C9F96E1B+4411]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6C9F8CFA0+575424]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF84FA0257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF8512EAF28+40]


Process finished with exit code 1


So what to do about it ?
I tried to use sleep for 2 seconds but it did not work?

This question is similar to: How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
